# if statement - not equal

Tags: linux, sh

How to make a *not equal* statement in sh?

```
if [ "$db_name" != `mysql -uroot -p${db_pass} -s -N -e "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name='${db_name}'"` ]; then
    echo "not found"
fi
```

## error

```
test.sh: 6: [: !=: argument expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote the arguments inside `[ and ]`:

```
if [ "$db_name" != "`mysql -uroot -p${db_pass} -s -N -e "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name='${db_name}'"`" ]; then    echo "fundet"
    echo "not found"
fi
```

If mysql command returns empty string OR if output with a space then you will get that error without quotes.